# Access paramater from constructor, from passing data to StatefulWidget Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem to access a data in second page after i get it from the first page.

```
class ProfileOthers extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileOthers({super.key, required this.data});

  final Map<String, dynamic> data; //I am hoping to make use of this data

  @override
  State<ProfileOthers> createState() => _ProfileOthersState();
}
```

I learnt to access it like this and display it on the page

```
'${widget.data['name']}'//part of data

'${widget.data['email']}' //part of data

'${widget.data['userImage']}'//part of data
```

Can i save the data in there to a variable? if it can be done, how to do it?. I want to use it for further use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have a stateful widget with the below structure:

```
class ProfileOthers extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileOthers({super.key, required this.data});

  final Map<String, dynamic> data; //I am hoping to make use of this data

  @override
  State<ProfileOthers> createState() => _ProfileOthersState();
}
```

You should have a corresponding state in the form:

```
class _ProfileOthersState extends State<ProfileOthers> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Follow the below steps to save to variables:

1. Create the variable in the state
2. Set the variable on the init state

Your state after the above steps should look like:

```
class _ProfileOthersState extends State<ProfileOthers> {
  late String email;
  late String name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    email = widget.data['email'];
    name = widget.data['name'];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

The variables `name` and `email` should hold the respective data. I assumed the data map contains the key 'email' and 'name'. You should use the exact keys present in your data.

Comment: Thankyou again brother xD it works, you save my day.